# How to set conditional breakpoint on returned value?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I want to break when a function I'm debugging returns specific value. I know how to use conditional breakpoints. I cal also see the return value in the *Locals* tab of the Visual Studio debug UI:

[image]

But how can I set a conditional breakpoint on that value?

Comment: Set a conditional breakpoint on each `return` statement in the function.

Comment: @MarkRansom What if the function is called from many places and you care about only one path? Or what if it's a function imported from DLL?

Comment: That should have been part of your question if those details are important.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done it previously is to create an `If` statement for that condition, then put some meaningless code inside it and put a breakpoint on that.

```
If (variable == condition){
    int i = 0; // breakpoint
}
```

Even if there is a specific way to do it in an IDE/editor, this works in all languages and all IDEs, that I know about anyway. Just remember to clean it up when you're done. I do my own "code review" before checking code into a code repo or before doing a QA build to look out for things like this, even though I don't use it very often.

Comment: Sometimes you may not be able to recompile code you're debugging or you may not want to, or there may be many return statements you're inspecting. I know how to use `if` statements and I usually do exactly what you proposed, but sometimes it's really impractical. Just as impractical as if you had to recompile code every time you wanted to add a normal breakpoint.

Comment: @TomášZato, well, then you need to decide if "impractical" and personal preference outweighs being able to do exactly what you want and learning values of variables in very specific cases. I've worked on projects with hundreds of web pages, dozens of classes, and hundreds of thousands of lines of code, and I've had to do exactly this. It took 15-20 sec to rebuild the solution, but it's what I did. It's not a perfect solution without any drawbacks, sure, but are those drawbacks worse than not knowing? That's something only you can know.

Comment: Also, I've recently worked on a project where the only way to test it was to move the EXE to another computer to run it. No debugging, no breakpoints, only console writes. It was a pain, and IDK if it compares to what you have, but sometimes "ya gotta do what ya gotta do" to get things done.

Comment: @computercarguy 1) "_It took 15-20 sec to rebuild the solution, but it's what I did._" 15-20 seconds to rebuild entire solution seems very low, in my experience. 2) "_the only way to test it was to move the EXE to another computer to run it. No debugging, no breakpoints, only console writes._" Application being in another machine, does not prevent it from being debugged remotely.

Comment: Temporarily instrumenting the code is a valuable debugging technique.  Not the only option, but definitely a good tool to have in one's toolbox.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, from what I read, you have to install software on the remote computer to allow that. As I needed to run this on a shared server, installing software that likely needs a restart isn't an option. Also, 20 sec for a rebuild is fairly long in my experience.

Comment: @computercarguy 1) I don't remember having to restart the computer, after installing said software. Even then: you don't even need to install it, you can just launch it from share, from computer containing it. 2) Speaking from the experience of full rebuilds taking 2-3 hours, which, recently, got reduced to 30-40 minutes, after enabling parallel build: 10-20 seconds is peanuts.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, if your compile time is that long, your project is way more massive than the majority of programmers. Because of that, your debugging solutions will be different than others. No solution to anything works 100% of the time for everyone.

Comment: @computercarguy I agree with that. I was just responding to 10-20 seconds being long build time for you. Typically, complete rebuilds, in our use cases, are not necessary that often: typically you need to just recompile relevant .dlls, while doing day-to-day tasks.

Comment: @computercarguy Project I work on certainly is quite different than majority of programmers. That's why asked this question. If using a variable was a viable solution, I'd do that. I'll still have to do that since there's no answer, but inability to break on return values has been bothering me for a while.